# XXX is not defined issue after putting the script into public/index.html - React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, api

I am trying to implement the Tyro payment gateway into my React application. (link: https://preview.redoc.ly/tyro-connect/PLA-4230/app/apis/pay/accept-an-online-payment/)

When I tried to run my application, it was saying that Tyro() was not defined. I have put the script tag in *public/index.html*, but it does not work.

The error is:

> [Eslint] "XXX is not defined (no-undef)"

Below is my *public/index.html* file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>React App</title>
    <script src="https://pay.connect.tyro.com/v1/tyro.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>

</html>
```

And my Tyro payment component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function TyroPayment() {
  const [tyroLibraryLoaded, setTyroLibraryLoaded] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (tyroLibraryLoaded === true) {
      init();
    }
  }, [tyroLibraryLoaded]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'https://pay.connect.tyro.com/v1/tyro.js';
    script.corssOrigin = 'anonymous';
    script.async = true;
    script.onload = () => setTyroLibraryLoaded(true);
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }, []);

  let paySecret;
  // JavaScript sample code
  async function init() {
    const tyro = Tyro();
    /*
    const response = await fetch('/create-order', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify({ apple: 55 }),
    });
    paySecret = await response.json().paySecret;
     */
    const paySecret = '$2a$10$KvfnNafAQguNViSHxLZsVuXv9ITJ56rCVFGIzDencnSB81TpvgAgm';
    await tyro.init(paySecret);

    const payForm = tyro.createPayForm();
    payForm.inject('#tyro-pay-form');
  }

  return (
    <div className='mainpage-container'>
      <form id='pay-form'>
        <div id='tyro-pay-form'></div>
        <button id='pay-form-submit'>Pay</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default TyroPayment;
```

How could I instantiate the Tyro() with the script tag, like step 3 in the documentation in React?

I have temporarily set the paySecret to a string to avoid the API call for now.

Comment: Is *"XXX"* literal?

Comment: OK, the OP has probably [left the building](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/979:_Wisdom_of_the_Ancients): *"Last seen more than a month ago"*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I googled and found that simply adding this line on top of the component will solve it:

```javascript
/* eslint no-undef: 0 */ // --> OFF
```

Now there isn't any problem running with the component :)

Comment: What is the explanation? What does it do? Suppress the error message? Why is it necessary? Is it sound (e.g., just removing the symptom may not be a good idea, especially for future code changes/updates)? If it is sound, why is it sound? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75895074/edit), not here in comments (*** *** *** *** *** ***without*** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).